# Netbeans manifest - layer.xml not found

Tags: maven, netbeans, manifest

I am working on a Netbeans RCP application with Flamingo ribbon and I have recently "mavenize" the whole project. Everything was working smoothly except for the Flamingo ribbon which was not displaying anymore.

I found that the problem is in the missing path to the `layer.xml` file in the manifest file.

In the previous (non-maven) project, the `manifest` was located in the root directory. In the new (maven) project, it is under `src/main/nbm/manifest`. I opened the manifest and inserted the path to the `layer.xml` file but it seems that the Layer.xml is not registered

This is how my manifest looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
OpenIDE-Module: cz.project.appcore
OpenIDE-Module-Localizing-Bundle: cz/project/appcore/Bundle.properties
OpenIDE-Module-Layer: cz/project/layer.xml
OpenIDE-Module-Requires: org.openide.windows.WindowManager
OpenIDE-Module-Specification-Version: 1.0
```

The structure of my project is standard maven structure:
`src/main/java/project/appcore` contains `Bundle.properties`
`src/main/java/project/` contains `layer.xml`
`src/main/nbm/` contains `manifest.mf`

Could you tell me where the problem is? Thank you for any tips...

EDIT: In short, in the non-Maven project, the paths in Manifest to the layers are present. In the Maven project, I had to copy them to the manifest manually but it didnt help and nothing gets displayed at all. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: POM.xml:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useDefaultManifestFile>true</useDefaultManifestFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any non java files are to be placed under src/main/resources, so your layer file should be at src/main/resources/cz/project/layer.xml.

Alternatively please check that the manifest file in generated jar file is actually showing entries from src/main/nbm/manifest.mf. If not, please check the maven-jar-plugin configuration . Typically your config you be equal to what gets generated by netbeans when you create a new nb platform module.